# Javascript group cart object by size

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have a javascript function that creates a Cart object and adds items everytime a user clicks add to Cart on the UI side and saving the objects to `mongodb`.

Problem is that this is not grouping by size when the user selects different sizes for the same product and it will just treat the item as the same size.

```
this.add = function(item, id, quantity, size){
        var storedItem = this.items[id];

    if (!storedItem) {

            storedItem = this.items[id] = {item: item, title: '', qty: 0, price: 0, shipping: 0, fullAmount: 0, size: ''};

    }

    if (quantity == 1)
    {storedItem.qty++;}
    else
        storedItem.qty =  +quantity + +storedItem.qty;


    storedItem.size = size;
    storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
```

**Object created:**

```
Cart {
  items:
   { '57fc2234abc3707804ae3523':
      { item: [Object],
        title: '',
        qty: 3,
        price: 359.85,
        shipping: 25,
        fullAmount: 0,
        size: 'S' },     < ----   selected one small and 2 mediums 
     '57fc2234abc3707804ae3524':
      { item: [Object],
        title: '',
        qty: 1,
        price: 84.95,
        shipping: 25,
        fullAmount: 0,
        size: 'S' } }
```

I'm struggling in putting together the logic to store the selected objects per Size and would like to be able to produce the following object:

**Object desired:**

```
Cart {
  items:
   {'57fc2234abc3707804ae3523':
      { item: [Object],
        title: 'Quartet Short',
        qty: 3,
        price: 359.85,
        shipping: 25,
        fullAmount: 0,
        size: 'S' },
      { item: [Object],
        title: 'Quartet Short',
        qty: 2,
        price: 359.85,
        shipping: 25,
        fullAmount: 0,
        size: 'M' }
   '57fc2234abc3707804ae3524':
      { item: [Object],
        title: 'Quartet Jersey',
        qty: 1,
        price: 84.95,
        shipping: 25,
        fullAmount: 0,
        size: 'S' } }
```

Is there an easy way to solve this or do i have to approach the cart object model differently?

Comment: Rather than indexing the cart items by item ID, do you have a different ID for each variant? A variant being different sizes, colours, etc.

Comment: As Rob said, there should be individual SKUs for each product combination as they are all unique. You can then use the SKU or an artificial SKU you create (e.g. product title + option(s)) as the keys.